# Create template for forms django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I currently have a login.html, which has inside it a form for login. All my forms need to look similar, however will have different content. At the moment my code for it looks like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ legend }}</legend>
        <div style="line-height:18px">{% block top %}{% endblock %}<br></div>
        <table class="form">
        {% for text,name,inputtype in formcontent %}
            <tr>
                <td class="right">
                    <label>{{ text }}:</label><br/>
                </td><td style="float:left">
                    <input name="{{ name }}" type="{{inputtype}}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    <input value="{{ button }}" type="submit">
    <div style="line-height:18px">
        <div class="err">
            {{ err }}
        </div>
        {{ bottom }}
    </div>
</fieldset></form>
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do it than to put variables into my urls.py (given that there may be multiple forms on hte page, I don't believe that this would work under all circumstances). A nice solution would be to create a class, but I don't know how to call this class from a page. I know it would involve making a tag, but I don't see how you can provide a 2d array as an argument from a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Crispy Forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) were made for this exact reason. I think they are exactly what you need.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I wanted. I only needed a method of how to do it, but this looks much better.

Comment: There is a link to an example (on gist) in the readme... https://gist.github.com/1838193

Comment: I installed it, but how do I create the tags? It chucks an error on the line in the template saying "{% load crispy_forms_tags %}"

Comment: Make sure to add crisy forms to your installed apps. Just follow their install instruction to the letter..